# Java: Braces make difference in if then else

Tags: java

In the following program, if I do not put braces with if then else statement, I get all statements executed resulting the scanner input asking me the question 3 times.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NestedIf
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

        System.out.println ("Who is the presiden of USA?");

        String response ="";
        String answer;

        answer = "Obama";

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        response = input.nextLine();

        if (response.equals(answer))
            System.out.println ("That is right");
        else  
            System.out.println ("That is wrong");
            response = input.nextLine();

            if (response.equals(answer))
            System.out.println ("That is right");
            else 
                System.out.println ("That is wrong");
                response = input.nextLine();

                if (response.equals(answer))
                System.out.println ("That is right");
                else 
                System.out.println ("That is wrong - Bye");


    }
}
```

result is:

Who is the presiden of USA?
Obama
That is right
Obama
That is right
Obama
That is right

If I put the braces and make the program like the following, the program asks the question and when I answer correct the other else statements are not executed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NestedIf
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

        System.out.println ("Who is the presiden of USA?");

        String response ="";
        String answer;

        answer = "Obama";

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        response = input.nextLine();

        if (response.equals(answer))
            System.out.println ("That is right");
        else  **{**
            System.out.println ("That is wrong");
            response = input.nextLine();

            if (response.equals(answer))
            System.out.println ("That is right");
            else **{**
                System.out.println ("That is wrong");
                response = input.nextLine();

                if (response.equals(answer))
                System.out.println ("That is right");
                else 
                System.out.println ("That is wrong - Bye");
            **}**
        **}**
    }
}
```

RESULT IS:
Who is the president of USA?
Obama
That is right

My question is why does braces make difference here, although I read through this forum that braces doesn't make any difference?

Comment: If you've read somewhere that braces don't make any difference, you 've read something incorrect.  They certainly do make a difference.

Comment: "I read through this forum" hehe) Read language specs and docs, not forums: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: Thanks Ordous for referring me to the docs. I am new so will take time to know these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not define braces after if or else, it will consider only one statement after it.
Your code will be same as below as logically :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NestedIf
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

        System.out.println ("Who is the presiden of USA?");

        String response ="";
        String answer;

        answer = "Obama";

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        response = input.nextLine();

        if (response.equals(answer))
        {
            System.out.println ("That is right");
        }
        else
        {  
            System.out.println ("That is wrong");
        }
            response = input.nextLine();

            if (response.equals(answer))
            {
                System.out.println ("That is right");
            }
            else
            { 
                System.out.println ("That is wrong");
            }
                response = input.nextLine();

                if (response.equals(answer))
                System.out.println ("That is right");
                else 
                System.out.println ("That is wrong - Bye");


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't change its behaviour depending on white-space, so in this case it would have no way of knowing where to end the block of code after the `else`.

A block of code can be defined by braces anywhere: `{ line1; line2; line3; }`. The syntax of an if statement or an else statement is: `if (condition) code;`. If you are using braces, then the code is replaced by a block of code, all of which is executed.

Java will interpret

```
if (condition)
  line1;
  line2;
  line3;
```

in the same way as

```
if (condition) line1;
line2;
line3;
```

because the only difference between them is white-space.

It will interpret

```
if (condition) {
  line1;
  line2;
  line3;
}
```

as

```
if (condition) { line1; line2; line3; }
```

again because the only difference is white-space.

Exactly the same applies for an `elseif` or `else` statement, or for that matter `try`, `catch`, `finally`, `while`, `for`, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Java compiler does not care about indentation.

So you need to add { and } around your code block.

```
if (something)
    instruction1
    instruction2
```

Will be understood by the compiler as:

```
if (something) {
    instruction1
}
instruction2
```

Answer (score 0):

No braces: if is only for the next line.
Braces: If statement valid for everything in between the braces.

Comment: I mean the braces after else. you can see two braces with ** that I put besides else and it makes the program run correctly WHY?

Comment: They should behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Read this also](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16528/single-statement-if-block-braces-or-no)

```
 int x=2;
 if(x==2)
 System.out.println(x);
 System.out.println("There is no braces . So this is not part of if").
 if(x==2)
 {
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println("Enclosed by braces . So this is  part of if").  
  // All the statements falls here ll be part of if
 }
```

If no braces , only first statement immediately followed by if ll be considered part of if.
   [Read this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Answer (score 0):

Without braces, the `if` and `else` clauses will only include a single statement.
You need to use braces if you want your `if` or `else` clauses to have more than one statement.

You have indented your source code as if you expect multiple statements to be executed for the `else` clause, and Java should "just know" thanks to the indentation. But in reality, the Java compiler does not care about indentation.

Without using braces to enclose your statements in the same branch, your program looks like this to the compiler:

```
    if (response.equals(answer))
        System.out.println ("That is right");
    else  
        System.out.println ("That is wrong");
    response = input.nextLine();

    if (response.equals(answer))
        System.out.println ("That is right");
    else 
        System.out.println ("That is wrong");
    response = input.nextLine();

    if (response.equals(answer))
        System.out.println ("That is right");
    else 
        System.out.println ("That is wrong - Bye");
```

Answer (score 0):

> By default the **JVM** consider every loop statement with a scope of
>   just one line.
>
> You can have increase the scope to a larger number of lines using the
>   `{}` symbol.
>
> Thus by doing that you increase the scope of the function to a larger
>   area and all the codes under it will be considered as a group under
>   the head.

**For Eg :**

If you have an if statement like this

```
   if (someCondition)
            statement 1;
   else  
       Statement 2
   statement 3;
```

Now the `if (someCondition)` have  `statement 1;` under its scope and `else` have  `Statement 2` under its scope. 
The `statement 3;` is not in any ways under the scope of `if` or `else`.

You can now increase the scope using the symbol `{` This symbol tell the Jvm that evey statements until the next `}` symbol is under the scope of the keyword precede.

If you get what i have explained clearly, then you will know what's the difference in the code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

You have the error because the if has only ONE line, the else has more than ONE line. If you doesn't put the brace, it like java put braces for you only on the next line.

ex:

```
 if(a==1) 
   foo();
 else
   bar();
```

Java act as

```
 if(a==1) {
   foo();
 } else {
  bar();
 }
```

but note this, if you doesnt put the braces on next code:

```
 if(a==1) 
   foo();
   bar();
 else
   bar();
```

Java act as you wrote this;

```
 if(a==1) {
   foo();
 } 
 bar();
 else {
  bar();
 }
```

I hope I help you.